How many times did Moses strike the rock?
In the Bemidbar story of Moses and Aaron striking the rock to provide water for the Israelites (Numbers 20) it is said the Moses struck the rock twice. However the Hebrew word used in my interlinear bible app is פַּעֲמָ֑יִם which appears to mean multiple times? Have I understood this correctly? Is that wherein the sin of Moses lay? The fact that he did not give YHWH honour for the miracle in saying "must we bring water out of this rock for you" and by striking the rock multiple times in anger?

פַּעֲמָ֑יִם means two times (dualform)

Good question Lisa. Striking rocks is a process related to letter transformations in Torah. It is not prohibited. The “sin of Moses” is only tangential to this story in BaMidbar. The actual sin was Moshe’s violating G-d’s prohibition against taking the mixed multitude out of Egypt together with the children of Israel. The mixed multitude are the source of the complaint that Moshe responded to.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_-0e4GF_mY

The Torah says פַּעֲמָ֑יִם - pa-'a-mayim, not פעמים  -pa-'a-mim. The difference is the vowel under מ (kamatz vs. hirik). The first one due to ending -aim is a special grammatical form for a pair of times, while the second due to ending -im is multiple times. The translation 2 times is correct.
The issue of the sin of Moshe is subject to a big controvercy (over 10 different explanations). Some discussion can be found here.
